# How to Reverse a string in Delphi with AnsiReverseString?

Tags: string, delphi, reverse

I am trying to reverse a string in Delphi. How can you reverse a string using the AnsiReverseString function?

What unit needs to be added and used? How does the function work?

Comment: Add `StrUtils` unit to your `uses` clause.

Comment: Nope, still doesn't work. Undeclared Identifier 'ReverseString'

Comment: they both are in strutils

Comment: A unit consisting of string utility functions.

Comment: Locate the word **uses** on top of your unit file, click on it, press F1.

Comment: "also gives me an error"  You have it the wrong way around - there is nothing to "work" or not until the compiler has successfully compiled your application, and the compiler error message is telling you why it can't.  Anyway, @TLama has told you how to fix it ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Like everyone says in the comments, add the `StrUtils` unit to your `uses` clause.

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StrUtils, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  source, target : AnsiString;
begin
  source := '123456789';
  target := AnsiReverseString(source);

  ShowMessage('Source = '+source);
  ShowMessage('Target = '+target);
end;

end.
```

Comment: I don't know when `AnsiReverseString()` was introduced, but `ReverseString()` does exist in D7. In D2009+, the `AnsiString` versions of `AnsiReverseString()` and `ReverseString()` were moved to the `AnsiStrings` unit.